# How do I manage the dates and the corresponding data on my fitness Application in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, database, flutter

How do I manage different data with dates based on the calendar(Calendar is in Application UI) in Flutter for a fitness tracker application.
I don't want to store the data permanently on a cloud database
I want to store it on the device's disk
Example: Choosing a date on the calendar will display the fitness activity (eg: calorie burnt ) the user performed on that day

I have no Idea on how to proceed

Comment: Question is unclear and The answer may be based on personal opinions.

Answer (score 0):

if you store it in device storage then clearing or uninstalling app will remove everything. so its your choice. btw you can use [sqflite plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) to store your data and then you can save your data with respect to your dates and then get it later.